# Recursively group rows and columns of python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, tuples, multi-index

I have a DataFrame representing the similarity of row items with column items with an index from 0 to 1.
I want to group the more similar items and create a new dataframe by dropping the grouped items rows and columns and then adding a single row and column both indexed with a tuple containing the 2 merged items, and then do the process again until I have grouped all the items.
For now I have come up with this code:

I first create 2 dataframes from a dictionary of tuples called gupt_seiff, one will stay the same while the other will be modified:

```
gupt_seiff_df = pd.DataFrame(index = workshops, columns = workshops)
for el in gupt_seiff:
    gupt_seiff_df.at[el[0], el[1]] = gupt_seiff[el]
gupt_seiff_df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = workshops, columns = workshops)
for row in gupt_seiff_df.index:
    for col in gupt_seiff_df.columns:
        gupt_seiff_df2.at[row, col] = gupt_seiff_df.at[row, col]
```

this is the result if I print gupt_seiff_df and gupt_seiff_df2:

```
              clav acciaio tornio montaggio 3 montaggio 1 tav controllo lavatrice montaggio 2 montaggio 4
clav acciaio           1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
tornio                 1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
montaggio 3            0.0    0.0         1.0         0.0           0.0       0.0    0.059823    0.075803
montaggio 1            0.0    0.0         0.0         1.0           0.0       0.0    0.019964         0.0
tav controllo          1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
lavatrice              1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
montaggio 2            0.0    0.0    0.059823    0.019964           0.0       0.0         1.0    0.884966
montaggio 4            0.0    0.0    0.075803         0.0           0.0       0.0    0.884966         1.0
              clav acciaio tornio montaggio 3 montaggio 1 tav controllo lavatrice montaggio 2 montaggio 4
clav acciaio           1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
tornio                 1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
montaggio 3            0.0    0.0         1.0         0.0           0.0       0.0    0.059823    0.075803
montaggio 1            0.0    0.0         0.0         1.0           0.0       0.0    0.019964         0.0
tav controllo          1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
lavatrice              1.0    1.0         0.0         0.0           1.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
montaggio 2            0.0    0.0    0.059823    0.019964           0.0       0.0         1.0    0.884966
montaggio 4            0.0    0.0    0.075803         0.0           0.0       0.0    0.884966         1.0
```

Now I want to find the items with max similarity, or the couples of (row, col) with the highest index in the dataframe. I managed to do it, the only things that may be worth saying are that the values in the diagonal are excluded, because they represent the similarity with an item and itself which is of course 1, and if there are couples outside the diagonal with the same similarity, it's not important which couple to merge first, so I just merge the first one.

Now I have a tuple with a couple of items with max similarity, which is going to be my first cluster. For example:

```
print(cluster)
('tav controllo', 'lavatrice')
```

So in this case what I want to do is to drop rows and colums named tav controllo and lavatrice, and add a row and a column indexed as ('tav controllo', 'lavatrice').
The expected result is something like this:

```
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[0], axis=0)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[0], axis=1)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[1], axis=0)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[1], axis=1)
new_row_col = pd.Series({cluster[0] + cluster[1]: 1}, name=cluster[0] + cluster[1])
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.append(new_row_col)
```

```
                       clav acciaio montaggio 2 tornio montaggio 3 montaggio 4 montaggio 1  tav controllolavatrice
clav acciaio                    1.0         0.0    1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0                     NaN
montaggio 2                     0.0         1.0    0.0    0.059823    0.884966    0.019964                     NaN
tornio                          1.0         0.0    1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0                     NaN
montaggio 3                     0.0    0.059823    0.0         1.0    0.075803         0.0                     NaN
montaggio 4                     0.0    0.884966    0.0    0.075803         1.0         0.0                     NaN
montaggio 1                     0.0    0.019964    0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0                     NaN
tav controllolavatrice          NaN         NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN                     1.0
```

But the problem here is that it works only if I concatenate the string names of the items.
What I want instead is to preserve the 2 distinct elements of the cluster tuple, because now I have to calculate the similarity values of the cluster with the other items, so for example the similarity of ('tav controllo', 'lavatrice') with 'clav acciaio' will be the mean of the items in the tuple with the new item:

```
gupt_seiff_df2.at[('tav controllo', 'lavatrice'), 'clav acciaio'] = (gupt_seiff_df.at['tav controllo', 'clav acciaio'] + gupt_seiff_df.at['lavatrice', 'clav acciaio'])/2
```

And so on to fill all the NaN values.
It can also happen that I have to calculate the mean between 2 tuples, so it will be the mean of the similiarity values of all the combinations between the first tuple and the second tuple. For example if I have a tuple with 3 items and a tuple with 2, I will have 3x2 = 6 similarity values, and then I will calculate the average.

I'm trying to preserve tuples indexing with this code:

```
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[0], axis=0)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[0], axis=1)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[1], axis=0)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.drop(cluster[1], axis=1)
new_row_col = pd.Series({cluster: 1}, name=cluster)
gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.append(new_row_col)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\Main_es.py", line 9, in <module>
    plant = Plant(loader_)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\plant.py", line 168, in __init__
    gupt_seiff_df2 = gupt_seiff_df2.append(new_row_col)
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7960, in append
    other.reindex(combined_columns, copy=False)
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4345, in reindex
    return super().reindex(index=index, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4811, in reindex
    return self._reindex_axes(
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4827, in _reindex_axes
    new_index, indexer = ax.reindex(
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2492, in reindex
    target = MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 175, in new_meth
    return meth(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\damia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 531, in from_tuples
    arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2537, in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

Finally, I want to repeat this process with the new gupt_seiff_df2. The final result must be a 1x1 DataFrame with index the cluster of all the items:

```
cluster_all_items = (clav acciaio, tornio, montaggio 3, montaggio 1, tav controllo, lavatrice, montaggio 2, montaggio 4)

                    (cluster_all_items)

(cluster_all_items)         1
```

Answer (score 1):

I case you're still looking for a solution ...

I think the problem with `.append` stems from an index misinterpreation. The tuple is most likely leading to a `MultiIndex` which then collides with the labels of the dataframe (I've looked a bit into the respective Pandas implementation but eventually got lost). Here's a workaround which isn't too bad:

With the sample frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 1]}, index=['A', 'B'])
```

```
   A  B
A  1  2
B  2  1
```

this

```
cluster = ('A', 'B')
df = df.append(pd.Series({cluster: 1}, name=cluster))
```

fails for the same reasons, but this

```
cluster = ('A', 'B')
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series({cluster: 1})])
df.columns = df.columns.to_list()[:-1] + [cluster]
```

results (`print(df)`) in

```
          A    B  (A, B)
A       1.0  2.0     NaN
B       2.0  1.0     NaN
(A, B)  NaN  NaN     1.0
```

which seems to have your desired structure.

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to solve this problem with AgglomerativeClustering from scikit right now!